# ExactTarget SOAP object for Authenticated User details or Account Users?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

If i have a username/password, which SOAP method/object can give me the details of the authenticated user?

Interested in knowing all their available details.

---

**update:**

I created a node library and used this function: https://github.com/blairanderson/node-exacttarget/blob/master/lib/exacttarget/exacttarget.js#L115-L143

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AccountUser object.  You can get 95% of the details [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_a_new_user_to_an_existing_account/) in the Create User example, scroll down to the SOAP packet.  Just use a "retrieve" instead of a "create".

Good luck!

Comment: How do I retrieve the associated business units and Roles?